# Stripe CLI triggering random events instead of payment_intent.succeeded

Tags: express, stripe-payments

This is my first time testing with Stripe and I can't wrap my head around this issue that I'm having. I copied the code for Node/Express from [this link](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/handling-payment-events?lang=node) (I just changed the port to 3000 and removed the bodyParser since I had already set it up with app.use(bodyParser.json())) and I successfully logged in to my account typing

```
stripe login
```

in the CLI.
After that, I set up my endpoint for webhook listening with

```
stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:3000/webhook
```

After everything seemed to be set up, I started testing, but I noticed somewhat of a random behaviour in the Stripe CLI: every time I tried triggering a payment intent success with

```
stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded
```

I got a different result, as shown below:

```
2020-07-04 14:25:32   --> charge.succeeded [evt_1H1AQxH9PqQvGDtCJ7ShdAQE]
2020-07-04 14:25:32  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:3000/webhook [evt_1H1AQxH9PqQvGDtCJ7ShdAQE]
2020-07-04 14:25:34   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_1H1AQzH9PqQvGDtCl8ajm7po]
2020-07-04 14:25:34  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:3000/webhook [evt_1H1AQzH9PqQvGDtCl8ajm7po]
2020-07-04 14:25:34   --> payment_intent.created [evt_1H1AR0H9PqQvGDtC1xty9l6R]
2020-07-04 14:25:34  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:3000/webhook [evt_1H1AR0H9PqQvGDtC1xty9l6R]
2020-07-04 14:28:46   --> charge.succeeded [evt_1H1AU5H9PqQvGDtCHJ95Jb7H]
2020-07-04 14:28:46  <--  [400] POST http://localhost:3000/webhook [evt_1H1AU5H9PqQvGDtCHJ95Jb7H]
```

I never triggered charge.succeeded nor payment_intent.created, but despite this they showed up in the CLI (as 400 errors) instead of the normal 200 payment_intent.succeeded. I tried console logging the event.type used by the switch statement in the Stripe Docs example above and it indeed showed that the events were charge.succeeded and payment_intent.created.

Now my question is: is this some sort of bug which hasn't been already fixed or am I doing something wrong? And maybe could anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance for your time :)

Answer (score 11):

Answer from one of Stripe's dev:

---

When you trigger an event with the Stripe CLI, under the hood it's making all of the requisite API methods to result in that event firing. In this case, it is creating and confirming a PaymentIntent.

To get a resulting payment_intent.succeeded event, you'll need to create a PaymentIntent (payment_intent.created will fire for this one). Then you need to confirm the payment intent and actually collect payment (which results in: charge.created, charge.succeeded, and payment_intent.succeeded).

For other event types like checkout.session.completed, many other events will fire that represent the objects that are prerequisite to get to a valid checkout.session.completed event.

If you only want to forward the payment_intent.succeeded event locally, (and it's a good idea when in production to enable only selected event types for your webhook endpoint), then you might want to pass the `-e` argument to `stripe listen` with the comma separated list of specific events you want to listen for. In this case you might update your listen command to:

```
stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:3000/webhook -e payment_intent.succeeded
```

Hope that helps. If you run into any issues, feel free to reach out to the team at support.stripe.com/contact or on IRC in the #stripe channel on Freenode.

---

I hope it helps somebody as much as it helped me!

Comment: This does noot work, do the same.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same experience. The same code, and the same listener running can trigger different webhooks.
When I create or cancel a user subscription from Stripe's dashboard, it can trigger no webhook at all, Sometimes some invoice webhooks, sometimes a series of up to 10 webhooks, including the create/cancel subscription webhook I'm expecting.

Gosh, stripe can be very frustrating. There are bugs at every step of the implementation process. Some I have reported on their github, and that did not get any response. Some I did not even report.

I just downloaded the new stripe CLI .deb package. Even such a simple thing as typing their brand name, they did it wrong. It's spelt "tripe CLI utility".

Anyway, I can only suggest you make sure you have all the latest libraries. They often upgrade their libraries to newer versions.

Make sure your stripe CLI is up-to-date. Same with `stripe` on your node server. Also open a new ticket on their github. Unlike Google for instance, I don't think Stripe has any engineers who monitor new Stripe related issues on SO.

Comment: Actually, I got an answer from one of the official Stripe devs on Reddit to the same question above, so I'm gonna leave it here for anyone who finds this.

Answer (score -2):

I had this error, with my web api based on net core5, it cannot solve it, but when downgrading to net core 3.1 as well as the MVC, everything was solved.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30165659)